# Read xlsx Template with openpyxl and rewrite as xls in Python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx, xls

I'm trying to use an xlsx as a template, to later read, modify and save it. So far I have used openpyxl, the problem is that in the development system, the computer does not support xlsx, only xls. I need to know how I can do to save it as xls.

Comment: Development systems should always have the same features as production systems. You're asking for trouble if this is not the case. You can convert XLSX to XLS using LibreOffice in headless mode but it's possible that stuff gets lost in the process.

Comment: I know, but it's the customer who gives us the development and production environments. As for conversion, isn't there a way to treat it all the time as XLSX and only save it as XLS at the end?
Or if I have the file in XLS, how can I use a package similar to openpyxl to perform the same function?

Comment: Those questions are beyond the scope of StackOverflow.